# Apache2 and PHP5 repository down?

Tags: apache-http-server, apt-get, raspberry-pi, php5

I've recently been trying to get PHP and Apache on my Raspberry Pi as to make it a web server but when I try to apt-get them from their respective repositories, it gives me a bunch of '404 not found'. On this  page: http://elinux.org/RPi_Tutorials#Setting_up_Apache2 is says that it's "offline" but is this just temporary or did it change addresses? Here's the tutorial I'm following: http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server

No luck with Cherokee either